# Display data in html extracted from pdf document in php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to display data extracted from PDF document. Here is sample data which I've got in raw format from pdf `55.0 450.0 320.0 GA350C CARDS 4 21 90.0 4 1 DIGCLR` This is one row where every space represent one column. I can extract each column with `substr()` function in PHP but I am not sure how to display data when there are three or five rows data in there, cos doesn't matter its one row or five row data will display in single line.

I can only count rows with no of space in it, here only one thing is fixed which is no of columns so so need to iterate loop efficiently.
If anyone has better idea plz let me know.

Here is string which I extracted from pdf doc with help of PdfParser.

```
5284 25/10/16 DATE JOB REC'D: DATE DUE: 26/10/16 JOB NUMBER: The Print Group CUSTOMER NAME: 30 days CONTACT: Tanya Bulley PHONE: (07) 3395 7248 FAX: (07) 3395 9462 ORDER NUMBER: 234456/277458 ADDRESS: The Print Group 88 Webster Road Geebung Qld 4034 Australia 5,289 QUOTE NO: PREVIOUS JOB NO: 0 2,000 Business Cards - Shed Company 2 KINDS JOB: DESCRIPTION: PRE-PRESS: Supplied Print Ready Files/ No Proof Required SIZE: BC 90 x 55mm PRINTED: CMYK 2/sides STOCK: 350gsm Gloss Art FINISH:Trim to size QTY: 2000 (1,000 each name) PACK: Carton Pack DELIVERY: 1 Point ACT [1]SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS: Artwork Received SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS: Out on Proof Approved Stock TYPE/ART CUTTING Proofing Pre Press Proofing 0.50 TRIMMING CARDS TRIM MAKE READY CARDS TRIM 90 x 55 STOCK 96.00 CARDS Sovereign Gloss 450x320/350 FINISHING PACK/DELIVERY PACK A4 Cartons 305x215/280 Standard Local Delivery (by we INK/CHEMICALS OUTSIDE WORK Delivery: The Print Group 88 Webster Road Geebung Qld 4034 Press Sheet Press Code Stock Code No. of Work & Turn No Up No. of Colours Front Back Description Ink Code Front Back Trim Size Depth Width Ink Notes 55.0 450.0 320.0 GA350C CARDS 4 21 90.0 4 1 DIGCLR
```

This is basically job order for printers and last line is job details. Right now its only one row for actual job details but in some order it can go upto 10 rows and so its hard to save it in database with proper column name. To grab words or details I used:

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end)
{
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

this function. I used this function like `$cust_name = GetBetween($a,'JOB NUMBER:','CUSTOMER NAME:');` I also used substr() php function to get some details and with these I've got everything apart from main data which is at last in string (I mentioned it above). I hope this explanation help you to figure out whole situation.

Comment: Hi there - could you perhaps add some code to illustrate what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I've edited my question. Hope this helps to visualize problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i try to explain with bulk of code and long description, but stackoverflow not allow me to writing that. i'm so frustated because i spend 2 hours to doing it with my notepad

now i will give you simple clue for doing this

1. Avoid to using <*table> tag, try to using <*div> (only abbyy can convert <*table> near perfectly). This optional requirement
2. Convert PDF to DOM TREE, i recommended convert to HTML, AND this must be automation via PHP.
   for Paid software: [Abbyy Fine reader](https://www.abbyy.com/en-apac/finereader/) or [Abbyy transformer](https://www.abbyy.com/en-apac/pdf-transformer/) (lite version)
   for Free software: pdftohtml from [poppler](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/)

> from my experience around 5years doing this, i recommended you to use
>   Abbyy. And ALL of Indonesian corporation which provide digital
>   newspaper clipping use this software (im pretty sure about this). If
>   you dont have money , you must know how to get that.(i cant say it
>   here)

3. Grab HTML DOM with regular expression (regex) or http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Another clue :

if you have problem to grab content using regex/htmldom,
1. try to get rid DOM that you dont need it. You can use preg_replace

```
[trash]
[YOUR_TABLE]
[trash]
```

then start to grab your content from this snippet

2. If you can edit PDF creation process, try to add unique word/string around your content

```html
[trash]
<div>this is title</div>
[YOUR TABLE]
<div>this is footer</div>
[trash]
```

so you can search your content around word THis is title and this is footer.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I've edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Also there is a problem in extracting pdf data, before I start extraction I  need to open pdf file in Acrobat and save it again than only PdfParser can read file. May be version problem, original version is in old format I think its 1.4

Comment: thanks for comment in my answer. so i can ask more question to solve this. i need your pdf not your extracted string from your pdf. you can use mediafire or somewhere else to attach this

Comment: You can view and download it here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9sc54mqHP9LX2tIZTdmTEFjZEE

Comment: sorry i forgot what is your server OS? do have root/administrators priviledge or not?

Comment: Using localhost and using php/Mysql, this is my development environment.

Comment: sorry for late reply. @katya.lee can we chat with hangout or whatsapp? i check 1. your pdf created using ilustrator CS6 not pdf library. 2. is that the final pdf template or you still can change the template? we need to know the final template because we will use regex or DOM to grab the content. otherwise the script will not work with different template. if you need fast respond from me you can chat me in plonknimbuzz@gmail.com

Comment: As you can see its company's confidential information so I changed some of the part in Illustrator CS6 but originally its created with library

Comment: hmm. i see. i think i cant help you now. maybe the others can. but if you want, you can email me your full pdf which i will keep it secret. i love to help people because that can help me to learn something new too. i hope others can help you. im so sorry

Comment: ok. u right. maybe i cant help you to solve this but i still can give you clue. i will create example for you. but while waiting me answer my question: 1. what library do you use for create pdf? 2. do you have access to edit pdf creator process?

Comment: If I create pdf there is no need to extract data from it so pdf creation is not in my hand. It's created by other software and thats why I need to extract data so I can use that data in other application. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: PdfParser can't work with my other pdf files. Do you know any class or anything which run with any kind of pdf document? I am waiting for your demo.

Comment: you cant use php lib. i realize that about 4 years ago. the only thing that u need is desktop application such as python, perl, vb, java. i recommended use abbyy or pdftohtml from poppler

Comment: there's many media monitoring corporation in jakarta indonesia. and all of themel that i know is use abbyy for mass automate pdf extraction. if cant automate the extraction, they and i will be face the never ending work. because in 1 day we meet 3000 article

Comment: Thanks but if I need to use external software I better open pdf file in Acrobat and save it as a text and grab that text. I am trying to get details from pdf file within my webpage which use php and mysql. PdfParser can open some document and can't open some so I can't be reply on that. May be I need to develop something to handle this job. Thanks for your time and interest.

Comment: PDF is divided in 2 different type. 1. PDF that containts searchable/selectable text (this can contain images too), ex: your example PDF which made by PDFlib or https://idrh.ku.edu/sites/idrh.ku.edu/files/files/tutorials/pdf/Text-searchable.pdf . 2. PDF that contains FULL IMAGE. example: You take a photo an invoice with your mobile camera thanconvert your pic album (jpg/png) into PDF or https://idrh.ku.edu/sites/idrh.ku.edu/files/files/tutorials/pdf/Non-text-searchable.pdf . if you are talking about PHP library , they only can extract Searchable PDF and cant extract non searchable PDF.

Comment: if you want to extract text from non-searchable PDF or an image or even captcha, you must convert that into Text first. this technique is called OCR (Optical character recognition). try to googling php ocr. But in your case, you just meet searchable text PDF. So it will be much easier. <newline> you tell me "if i want to use external apps, i better open acrobat", come on,, did you mean i must convert my 3000 article/day by click and click? i didnt do anything, my server doing that for me. he OCR my article, convert it into HTML. extract <*title> as title, the rest is saved as content in db

Comment: if you dont want to use abbyy or you dont know how to work with abbyy its fine. You still can extract it with pdftohtml from proppler. then you grab the content with regular expression. if you have difficulty to use regex, you cant grab it with htmldomparser library (read my answer above)

Comment: Thanks for your time and support. you can mail me how to get abbyy to katya.lee12@mail.com. Want to see how it goes and how can I utilize.